# custom rendering for qml element

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

is it possible to render your own graphics with your own context in qml? i found an example (\scenegraph\openglunderqml) which shows how to render your own graphics in qml, it simply uses the QQuickWindow::beforeRendering() signal and calls it's own paint function with it's own rendering method, but the thing is it is using the context that is provided by qml, my question is it possible to use your own context here?

Comment: I know how to use custom context in QWidget, this problem could be solved if there is a way to embed a QWidget inside QML. It is possible to embed QML into QWidget but as far as iI know you can not embed a QWidget inside QML.

Comment: Check out `Qt` 5 source and look at how they implement their own controls. Stunts, such as embedding a `QWidget` into `QML` should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can mix QWidget with QML easily either. I was looking at this too and there are claims you can create your own qml item and do all your own rendering. This [link](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtquick/scenegraph-openglunderqml.html) might help too. It shows OpenGL Under QML.